# keras with tensorflow runs fine, until I add callbacks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorboard

I'm running a model using Keras and TensorFlow backend. Everything works perfect:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(dim, input_dim=dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=12, 
                    batch_size=100, 
                    validation_split=0.2, 
                    shuffle=True, 
                    verbose=2)
```

But as soon as I include logger and callbacks so I can log for tensorboard, I get

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_layer_input_2' with dtype float and shape [?,1329]...

Here's my code: (and actually, it worked 1 time, the very first time, then ecer since been getting that error)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(dim, input_dim=dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])

logger = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/tf_logs',
                                     write_graph=True,
                                     histogram_freq=1)

history = model.fit(X, Y, 
                    epochs=12,
                    batch_size=100,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    shuffle=True,
                    verbose=2,
                    callbacks=[logger])
```

Comment: Since it worked the first time I would try to restart the whole session. Probably there are some variables in your memory which have not been deleted.

Comment: I tried a %reset and hadn't worked. But tried a complete restart for the kernal and it did the trick. any suggestions on how to clear that without restart the kernal? kind of annoying to have to do that after everytime.

Comment: try this: `from keras import backend as K
cfg = K.tf.ConfigProto()  
cfg.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  
K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=cfg))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tensorboard` callback uses `tf.summary.merge_all` function in order to collect all tensors for histogram computations. Because of that - your summary is collecting tensors from previous models not cleared from previous model runs. In order to clear these previous models try:

```
from keras import backend as K

K.clear_session()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(dim, input_dim=dim, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mae'])

logger = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/tf_logs',
                                 write_graph=True,
                                 histogram_freq=1)

history = model.fit(X, Y, 
                epochs=12,
                batch_size=100,
                validation_split=0.2,
                shuffle=True,
                verbose=2,
                callbacks=[logger])
```